# What preparation is needed to apply knockdown ceiling

Tags: ceiling

A 25 year old ceiling had popcorn and was scraped 5 years ago.  It is an eyesore, so the decision has been made to apply knockdown.  What (if any) preparation is required to apply knowckdown?  Any lessons learned area appreciated.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have a fairly rough surface at this point. When I refurbish texture over a large area I do a full skim finish first. If you want your texture to look new and professional you can't go over a mess. Standard or topping joint compound work well.

So, skim, scrape any ridges, and skim again. Repeat until it's like new, then sand lightly.

Answer (score 0):

Bonding primer is never a bad idea. Seals and solidifies what's there now, and lets the new finish adhere well.

Oh, and some decent shoulder warm-up exercises are a good idea too...